# Regex to find specific url type

Tags: c#

How would i write a regex to find a match for the following type of URL:

> https://domain.com/account/hello/username121/23424323-EEA1419

In the above domain.com/account/hello/ are always the same, username121 and the last string change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like the following

`https://domain.com/account/hello/[a-z0-9]+/[0-9]+-[A-Z0-9]+`

This assumes that only username and last part changes

Comment: Can i make that somehow match anything that comes after https://domain.com/account/hello/ ?